# Why does openssl client show TLSv1.0 as unsupported when nmap is showing it as supported?

Tags: tls

I tried to identify what TLS protocols an internal web app supports over http1.1 and ended up on identification with `nmap` and `openssl`:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 127.0.0.1

openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -tls1_1
```

- `nmap` is returning TLS1.0 is opened, whereas `openssl s_client` is outputting error `131A0000`

Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Do not post images when plain text will do.

Comment: What ciphers does the SSL certificate support? [Edit] your question to include this information as text.

Comment: Check [this Q/A on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568215/openssl-v1-1-1-ubuntu-20-tlsv1-no-protocols-available).

Comment: Likely, TLS 1.0 & 1.1 were turned off because they've been deprecated since 2021. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: What exactly has a TLS certificate to do with that?
I checked the similar issue however the solution does not explain the behaviour of openssl client.
I know TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 were turned off. I needed to enable TLS1.0 due to old internal application. However I see two different responses to that from curl and from openssl client.